# How to vertically align several images css?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have three images all in a box. How can I align them in css so that there is an even amount of space between them, as well as the top and bottom borders of the box?

At the moment my code looks something like this:

```
<div id="topRight">
    <img src="image1.jpg" width="300px">
    <img src="image2.jpg" width="300px">
    <img src="image3.jpg" width="300px">
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#topRight {
float: right;
margin-top: 200px;
width: 300px;
height: 630px;
padding-top: 10px;
background-color: white;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0px 2px 3px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0) 0px -1px 2px;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vertically display images using `<ul>...</ul>`

Each image is put into an `<li>` tag !

```
<ul id="topRight">
    <li><img src="image1.jpg" width="100px"></li>
    <li><img src="image2.jpg" width="100px"></li>
    <li><img src="image3.jpg" width="100px"></li>
</ul>
```

Then the bullets are removed using `list-style:none;`

`margin:value 0;` can be used to provide equal spacing.

Now Additional Equal spacing can be added using `padding:value;`

For Vertical Spacing alone use `padding:value 0;`;

WORKING DEMO -> [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eVQ4h/4/)

Comment: I have styled a list elseware, so how do I refer specifically to this list of images in the css (to avoid affecting the styling of the other list)?

Comment: Thats why we used a selector (i.e., an id) in this case,`topRight` .. so that the other `<ul>` wont get affected ! updated the Fiddle Demo .. check it out

Answer (score 0):

set height to 100% so the border will will be at the end of the images.

Answer (score 0):

include this code into style :

```
img {
   margin: 0px auto;
}
```

or

```
img {
   margin: 10px;
   position :relative;
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franvarn/An73Q/)

```
#topRight {
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0) 0px 2px 3px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0) 0px -1px 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
}

img {
  padding-bottom:10px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```